# How i can display an section after submitting

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the result box after the submit. As you can see, I have a section that contains the name of the quiz and another section that includes the question list and the rest is the result box. I want that before submitting, the old screen contains the name of the quiz and the result box isn't displayed. After selecting and submitting, the section of the name of the quiz keeps staying on the screen, the question list becomes disable and the result box will appear on the new screen.

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot.

```js
/* the question list disapper */
function disappear(event) {
    const disapp = event.currentTarget;
    disapp.removeEventListener("click", disappear);

    const startquiz = document.querySelector("#introduction");
    const quizlist = document.querySelector("#quiz");

    startquiz.classList.add("hidden");
    quizlist.classList.remove("hidden");

    const questionlist = document.querySelector("#attempt-quiz");
    questionlist.scrollIntoView();
}
const disapp = document.querySelector("#introduction button");
disapp.addEventListener("click", disappear);

/* click to any of the answer */

function openPresent(event) {
    const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
    for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        answer[i].style.backgroundColor = originalAnswerArray[i];
    }
    const input = event.target.querySelector("input")
    input.checked = true;
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

}

const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
let i;

let originalAnswerArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    originalAnswerArray.push(answer[i].getAttribute("name"));
    answer[i].addEventListener("click", openPresent);
}

/* the score */

function score() {
    const ques01 = document.ques01.question1.value;
    const ques02 = document.ques02.question2.value;
    const ques03 = document.ques03.question3.value;
    const ques04 = document.ques04.question4.value;
    const ques05 = document.ques05.question5.value;
    const ques06 = document.ques06.question6.value;
    const ques07 = document.ques07.question7.value;
    const ques08 = document.ques08.question8.value;
    const ques09 = document.ques09.question9.value;
    const ques10 = document.ques10.question10.value;

    let count = 0;
    if (ques01 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques02 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques03 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques04 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques05 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques06 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques07 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques08 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques09 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques10 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    console.log(count);

}

const input = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
for (let k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
    input[k].addEventListener("click", score);
}

function totalscore() {
    document.write('hello');
    const ques01 = document.ques01.question1.value;
    const ques02 = document.ques02.question2.value;
    const ques03 = document.ques03.question3.value;
    const ques04 = document.ques04.question4.value;
    const ques05 = document.ques05.question5.value;
    const ques06 = document.ques06.question6.value;
    const ques07 = document.ques07.question7.value;
    const ques08 = document.ques08.question8.value;
    const ques09 = document.ques09.question9.value;
    const ques10 = document.ques10.question10.value;

    let count = 0;
    if (ques01 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques02 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques03 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques04 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques05 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques06 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques07 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques08 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques09 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }
    if (ques10 == 'option 1') {
        count++;
    }


}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #222222;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 700px;
    height: 80px;
}

#coursename {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ee3322;
}

header span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#MRN {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

#MRN span {
    background-color: #ffee00;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    font-weight: bold;
}

#MRN div {
    background-color: #ffee00;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    padding: 10px;
}

article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#quiz-name {
    background-image: url(../starter_pack/images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: middle;
    width: 700px;
    height: 425px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-family: Pangolin, "Trebuchet MS", cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#author {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 18px;
}

#introduction {
    width: 700px;
}

#introduction h2,
#introduction p {
    margin: 18px 0 18px 0;
}

#startquiz {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 18px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 18px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #0d8bf2;
}

#attempt-quiz {
    width: 700px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#attempt-quiz p {
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

form {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.option {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.location {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #d4edda;
}

#submit {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 18px;
}

#submit button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 18px;
}

#submit button:hover {
    background-color: #46a049;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML Quiz</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pangolin:400,700|Proxima+Nova" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer="true"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <p id="coursename"><strong> WPR </strong> </p>
        <div id="MRN">

            <!-- <div>M</div> 
     <div>M</div> 
     <div>M</div> 
     <div>M</div> 
     */ -->
            <span>M</span>
            <span>E</span>
            <span>R</span>
            <span>N</span>
        </div>
    </header>


    <article>
        <section id="quiz-name">
            <h1 id="hello">HTML Quiz</h1> <br>
        </section>

        <p id="author"> By Minh Duc Nguyen </p>

        <section id="introduction">
            <h2> The Test </h2>


            <p>The test contains 10 questions and there is no time limit.</p>

            <p>The test is not official, it"s just a nice way to see how much you know, or don"t know, about HTML.</p>

            <h2>Count Your Score</h2>
            <p>
                You will get 1 point for each correct answer. At the end of the Quiz, your total score will be displayed. Maximum score is 10 points.
            </p>
            <div id="startquiz">
                <h2>Start the quiz</h2>
                <p> Good luck!</p>
                <button name="button" type="button">Start the HTML quiz ❯ </button>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="attempt-quiz">
            <div id="quiz" class="hidden">

                <p><strong> Question 1 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 1</p>
                <form name="ques01">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 2</p>
                <form name='ques02'>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 3 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 3</p>
                <form name="ques03">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 4 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 4</p>
                <form name="ques04">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 5 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 5</p>
                <form name="ques05">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 6 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 6</p>
                <form name="ques06">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 7 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 7

                </p>
                <form name="ques07">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 8 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 8</p>
                <form name="ques08">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 9 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 9</p>
                <form name="ques09">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 10 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 10</p>
                <form name="ques10">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>

                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                        <div class="location"> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>



                <div id="submit">
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" onclick='totalscore()'>Submit your answer</button>
                </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="review-quiz">

            <div id="tryagain">
                <h2></h2>
                <p></p>
                <button name="button" type="button">Try Again </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</body>

</html>
```

`